# Dependency Injection in python (dependend on module availability)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am working on plugin for GPS IDE, and I would like to have two versions of it:
1. GPS plugin - run with GPS
2. Standalone app - run without GPS

One of plugin's features is line highlighting. When plugin is run as standalone app it is impossible. I created gpshelper class for that, which imports GPS module. Import throws ImportException when running as standalone app (because GPS module is not available).
I wonder how I should inject this gpshelper module to my plugin.

Highlighting is performed during highlight method call (this method call gpshelper).

Is it ok, when inside highlight method I do this:

```
try:
    import gpshelper
except ImportError:
    warnings.warn('Program is running as python app (not GPS plugin)')
```

Maybe there is some other/better way how to do that?

Comment: Is the highlight method called multiple times? If so, you can set a variable like `USE_GPS = False` when the error is raised, and then only execute the `try/except` block once.

Comment: It is called one time per user action (after double click on gtk.treeview list). But my question is more about 'clean code' than performance.

Answer (score 2):

Define a gps_highlight routine as part of the try part importing gpshelper. Then call that routine from your existing code. In the except part define a dummy gps_highlight function. That way you keep your calling code clean:

```
import warnings

try:
    import gpshelper
    def gps_highlight(*args, **kw):
        return gpshelper.highlight(*args, **kw)
except ImportError:
    warnings.warn('Program is running as python app (not GPS plugin)')
    def gps_highlight(*args, **kw):
        return None

# after this you can safely call gps_highlight with the right parameters
# as needed by gpshelper.highlight
```